# Encrypted folder mounted by a cron job, won't keeps mounted

Tags: linux, mount, cron, ecryptfs

I have an A.sh script that queries a server; retrieves the mount password and mount the Private folder in the client.

Then I have a Init.sh script that first check the internet connection status and later executes A.sh.

If I execute manually A.sh the Private folder will be available across all that user sessions. But if I execute Init.sh or A.sh through a cron job, the output will show that the folder has being mounted, but that won't be reflected elsewhere.

- A.sh retrieves the mount password for the folder
- Adds it to the keyring `printf "%s" "$PASS" | sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek -`
- From the output retrieves the signature and fnek hashes.
- And finally mounts the folder with `sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_sig="$SIGNATURE",ecryptfs_fnek_sig="$FNEK",ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,no_sig_cache,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd="$PASS" "$PRIVATE_FOLDER" "$MOUNT_POINT"`

I know that it gets mounted because the output in the logs the line `Mounted eCryptfs` is shown. I don't know why it gets umounted by the end of the script.

The cron job is run under that user crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs

> auto-mount, auto-umount [empty files] - if they exist, the pam_ecryptfs.so module will (assuming it is loaded) automatically mount/unmount this encrypted directory when the user logs in/out

"If they exist" refers as files in `~/.ecryptfs/` directory.

If you want to get the Private folder automatically umounted when your ssh  or local session ends `touch ~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` will suffice.

But it seems this auto umounting behavior will be kept as long the *pam_ecryptfs.so* is loaded in memory on non-interactive sessions as cron jobs are. Even if there's no `~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` file set.

Commenting out the line

```
session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

on `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` will stop this auto umounting on non-interactive sessions like cron jobs.